# why func2 works without ValidateBeforeSave:false but func1 doesn't?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

```js
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    required: [true, 'A user must have a name'],
  },,
  password: {
    required: [true, 'A password must be set'],
  },
  passwordConfirm: {
    required: [true, 'password confimr must be set'],
    validate: {
      validator: function (val) {
        return val === this.password;
      },
    },
  },
  passwordResetToken: String,
});
    
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

My schema with custom and built-in validators.

```js
userSchema.methods.createResetToken = async function() {
  const plainToken = "some string"
  this.passwordResetToken = "some strange looking string"
  return plainToken;
};
```

The function above sets values of some properties in the Schema and returns a string to func1.

```js
const func1 = async (req, res, next) => {
  const user = await User.findOne({ //getUser });
  const plainToken = await user.createResetToken();
  await user.save({ validateBeforeSave: false });
  //more code
};
```

The function above runs only when `ValidateBeforeSave` is set to false.

```js
const func2 = async function (req, res, next) {
  let user = await User.findOne({
    // get user
  });

  user.password = req.body.password;
  user.passwordConfirm = req.body.passwordConfirm;
  user.passwordResetExpiresAt = undefined;
  user.passwordResetToken = undefined;
  user = await user.save();
  //more code
};
```

The function above runs without need of `ValidateBeforeSave` set to `false`.

Comment: Are you sure that `func1` sets all required attributes in `user`, in particular `password` and `passwordConfirm`?

Comment: @HeikoTheißen func1 doesn't set any required attribute, it sets value of "passwordResetToken" in the current document, it actually makes sense that it works without a problem bcuz validateBeforeSave is set to false since no validation runs. but in func2 I haven't specified the value for name and email, but the code works despite the fact that validateBeforeSave isn't set to false.

Comment: But isn't the `user.name` already present in the result of `User.findOne`? An `email` attribute is not mentioned anywhere.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen I have simplified my code, in my main code email is also included and required.  User.findOne fetches the user from the database and  it already is a pre-existing user therefore it has all the attributes within itsef, the same goes for both functions, func1 and func2. they both get it from database. but one saves with validateBeforeSave the other doesn't. in both cases I manipulate document properties.

Comment: Sorry, I am at my wits' end. A side remark: I consider the `passwordConfirm` field a pure user convenience function, which prevents mistyped passwords. It can be checked on the client and need not be transferred to (and validated by) the database.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen You are right, the passwordConfirm isn't transferred to database, I have a pre save middleware function which runs and sets the confirmPassword to undefined, it's more of a schema level verification and does not get into the database.

Comment: But if it is not transferred to the database, then `user = await User.findOne({ //getUser });`in `func1` cannot contain it, therefore the validation in the subsequent `user.save` must fail. That explains your observation.